# Understanding LSP Python

Tags: python, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

So the LSP says that if S is a subtype of T, then any instance of S should be able to replace any instance of T without altering any of the desirable properties of that program.

Does that mean that this would fail the LSP because when you do `dev_1.print_name()`(substituting the instance of the subclass with that of the base class -ish), you get an unexpected result(failure) because you haven't initialised the name?

```py
@dataclass
class Employee:
    name: str

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)

class Developer(Employee):
    def __init__(self, work_from_home: bool):
        self.work_from_home = work_from_home
    

dev_1 = Developer(True)
dev_1.print_name()
```

And the way to fix that would be to change the Developer class to something like this, to be compatible with all the methods of the `Employee` class?

```py
class Developer(Employee):
    def __init__(self, work_from_home: bool, name:str):
        self.work_from_home = work_from_home
        super().__init__(name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  As your code is written, creating an `Employee` will require that its `name` attribute be given a value.  But as written, your code will not initialize `name` when creating a `Developer`.  Just as you say, this leads to a `Developer` object not behaving like an `Employee` object, so it violates LSP.

Your solution of adding a constructor that takes a value for the `name` attribute does indeed solve the problem.  The standard way to get this same behavior is to annotate `Developer` as a data class as well so that you get the proper constructor for free:

```
@dataclass
class Employee:
    name: str

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)

@dataclass
class Developer(Employee):
    work_from_home: bool

    def print_developer(self):
        print(f"Developer {self.name} does{'' if self.work_from_home else ' not'} work from home")

def main():
    dev_1 = Developer("Jack", False)
    dev_1.print_developer()
```

Result:

```
Developer Jack does not work from home
```

You can also treat a `Developer` object as an `Employee`:

```
emp_1 = Developer("Jill", True)
emp_1.print_name()
```

Result:

```
Jill
```

Comment: What I meant was that in the first block of code, dev_1.print_name() can't ever work because there is no way to initialise `name` in the `Developer` subclass. Whereas `emp_1.print_name()` can work if you do `emp_1 = Employee('Jack')`. Sorry if I was unclear, or if my logic is still flawed haha

Comment: I apologize for my original answer.  I guess because `Developer` was not annotated with `@dataclass` I missed that `Employee` was.  Please check out my new answer.  I hope it helps.

Comment: The failure to properly initialize the object is an LSP violation. An instance of `Developer` *without* a `name` attribute cannot be used by code that expects an instance of `Employee` *with* a `name` attribute.

Comment: @chepner - I guess you're technically correct, and maybe right on as well.  I had missed the `@dataclass` annotation when first considering this question.  With that not there, there would be no way to initialize `name` for an employee either, and so they'd both have the broken behavior.  As it is now, you're technically correct, and I can see now that this lack of initialization of `name` for a `Developer` might be the point f the question.  Thanks for pointing this out.  I'll ditch my answer.